# Is it possible to capture finger prints using android phone scanner and save the finger prints to local sqlite

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-sqlite, fingerprint

I am developing a react-native project for data capturing of farmers and I need to get their finger prints as well. Can I achieve this with the devices' scanner and how..

Comment: Hello, did you ever find a solution for this? I need the same at this moment

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. On Android, for device built-in fingerprint scanners, fingerprint identifying data is stored securely on the device and is inaccessible to app developers.

Comment: Thanks so much for saving me time. Do you have idea about any finger print scanner that I can use with react-native. something like(digital persona device). I cant find digital persona finger print scanner sdk for react-native

Comment: @AuwalAliyu: Sorry, but I have never researched external fingerprint scanners.